# ASP.NET MVC on Azure Run Job "Every Hour"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, azure

I have an ASP.NET MVC site that I am running in Azure. There is a job I want to kick off once an hour to update data.

I currently have an Azure job setup once an hour to hit my controller/action method which calls into the "data load" service.

```
    public JsonResult Load()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DataService.LoadData());

        return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This way it kicks off the process and allows the Azure job to "succeed"

However, the job is now running on it's own thread which I don't believe is safe. I have the code wrapped in a try/catch and sometimes I see a thread abort logged. How should I go about running this 5-10 minute data load successfully without a thread aborting?

Also, I only want the job to run again exactly 1 hour after the 5-10 minute data load has happened.

So if the load kicks off at 8 AM and finishes at 8:10, I don't want the next data load to happen until 8:11 (and so on)

Obviously I'm not currently setup for this. Theoretically I could setup a job to ping every minute and see if it's "time to run", but I don't necessarily want to do this.

Comment: Are you using web and worker roles or the websites thing?  If using the roles, why not create an XS instance of a worker role to do the background processing?

Comment: I am not using worker roles. Just using a "website" that I am pinging with the scheduler. The problem I see with the worker role is that would have to live outside my current MVC solution

Comment: True, but if your business/db logic is in its own project in your solution, then a simple reference would get you the same logic/code.  Just my 2cents as one of the primary worker role reasons is for running recurrent code.  Websites typically suck at that (app pool recycling / how often the web app goes to sleep / etc)

Comment: Use Azure Functions. That's what it was built for. It's pretty great. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview

Answer (score 0):

As it was already mentioned in the comments, you would be better off separating "long-running" task from your website, you can still keep it in the same solution, as separated project, to make sharing business logic code simpler and  just deploy to two different environments - Website + WebJob, Website + WebWorker

You can try to mitigate the issue with long running task on IIS, see some resources here:

- Solution based on [IRegisteredObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.iregisteredobject.aspx) - WebBackgrounder - [gihub](https://github.com/NuGet/WebBackgrounder/tree/master/src/WebBackgrounder) and [corresponding blog post, recommended read](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/)
- Really nice summary of all techniques - [Scott Hanselman - How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Non of the above guarantees that your task/job will finish, recycle will kill it anyway.

If your "long-running" task is preloading data for MVC you can still extract it to separated service and make your data available for calls through Cache (worker populates Cache), DocumentDB/SearchAPI (worker prepoulates them every hour), Self hosted API in WorkerRole.

You can schedule your task an hour after previous finished with Service Bus - by adding message to a queue with [ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.scheduledenqueuetimeutc.aspx) set - it should be sufficient if your task is not millisecond-sensitive.